# Updating an individual procedure in an Oracle package

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

Using Oracle 10g.

I'm writing a script to apply the delta changes made on our development system to our stage system.

Is there a way to modify or insert an individual procedure within a package without including the entire package contents in my script?  I think the answer is no, but I wanted to be sure because it's going to be pretty ugly to have to include the entire contents of any modified packages when the changes were small.

Comment: If it seems ugly, perhaps your packages are a bit on the large size? - e.g. if too many unrelated procedures and functions are bundled into "super packages" it may be a good idea to split them along logical lines into separate packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry but your gut instinct is correct.  The unit of change is the PACKAGE BODY.

Not sure why you think it's ugly though.  surely it's just a matter of calling a script for the package?

Answer (score 2):

No, a package body must be replaced as a whole.  Rather than include the code for several packages in a single script, I would create a file per package spec and a file per package body.  You can then write a "meta-script" to run the required package changes in SQL Plus:

```
@@package1.spc
@@package1.bdy
@@package2.bdy
```

Comment: you could break this concept down even further and have a file per procedure in the package header and body. This way your "meta-script" can pull together the pieces it needs at build time but it makes change tracking easier in your source control system, especially for large procedures.

Comment: Do you mean breakdown the script of a package body into multiple files with each package body procedure in a separate file? Eek. Think I'd avoid that. Change tracking is easier in a single file with diffs.

Comment: No, no, no, I didn't mean that! Each file contains one **complete** package spec or body.

Answer (score 0):

Faced same problem. Simply created separate package for a procedure that changes frequently.